# Python Xrange in Java

Tags: java, python

How to write below Python code fragment in Java.? I'm new to Python, Seems there are slice operator and iteration function as well. Correct me If I'm wrong.!

```
def func(a):
    x = 1
    y = 1
    for num in xrange(a + 1, 2 * a + 1): x *= num
    for num in xrange(1, a + 1): y *= num
    return x / y / (a + 1)

print func(input() +1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice operator is not relevant here. To convert this to java, all you need know is that the `for num in xrange(a, b)` is equivalent to

```
for (int num=a+1; num < 2*a+1; num++) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, then why this remaining part.? : x *= num

Comment: @Priyanka: it's the same, just add `;` at the end of the lines

Comment: ok, understood, I add whole code by editing Question.I confuse how to use num variable outside of the xrange function.?